# importing from parent directory fails in google app engine (python27)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-import

I've been working on some GAE project. This is the directory structure

```
Project Home
|-- config.py
|-- util.py
|-- app.yaml
|-- main.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- login
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- login.py
|   `-- login.yaml
```

My objective is to import the **util.py** in the **login.py** file, which I've not been able to do successfully after having tried with many options. I came across some similar posts regarding this on stack overflow, but none of those are helping me doing this job.

P.S: I'm using python runtime environment 2.7

**Edit:**

using `import util` inside **login.py** gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<whatever>/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "<whatever>/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "<whatever>/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "<whatever>/<Project Home>/login/login.py", line 31, in <module>
    import util
  ImportError: No module named util
```

Comment: `import util.py` should work. Any errors?

Comment: My guess  is, there is some issue with the project root not in path. Can you successfully import from `from .. import util`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have two yaml configuration files, app.yaml and login.yaml, so you must be using the Google App Engine Modules API.

When you use the Modules API, the login module runs inside a separate Python virtual environment as a separate self-contained instance. It cannot 'see' the contents of the parent directory.

There are three solutions:

(a) Duplicate your 'util.py' file by placing it inside the login directory.

(b) Place login.py and login.yaml in the root directory.

(c) Don't use the Modules API and just have a single default module with a single configuration file, app.yaml. Give app.yaml two URL handlers, one for main.py and one for login.py. I would personally recommend this option, as it is the simplest.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you never use the `.py` extension in your code. The syntax is just:

```
import util
```

Comment: Does util import logging, by any chance?

Comment: No, util.py uses these 3 modules

`from google.appengine.api import modules`, 
`from config import app_globals`, 
`import re`
Here `config.py` is in the same directory as `util.py` is in.

Comment: OK, does config import login? I'm just trying to rule out a circular dependency.

Comment: No, config has 2 imports : `from google.appengine.api import memcache` and `import yaml`